# side by side Bootstrap table with *ngFor in Angular 5

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I want my table to be side by side not below each other. I tried table formats of Bootstrap but it is not working in my app. This is code:

```html
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">
      <table class="table">
        <tr *ngFor="let property of this.getKeyValues(this.navbarService.countriesOzetInfo[0].properties)">
          <div *ngIf="this.navbarService.countriesOzetInfo[0].properties[property] != null">
            <td>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" role="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
                <br/>Apps</a>
            </td>
          </div>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to generate cells which keep appending to each other horizontally rather than rows which keep appending vertically?

Comment: You should add more info. Should you have to use table? Bootstrap 3?

Comment: I want those buttons side by side horizontally. I may try 6 button in one row  and then 6 other in other roaw. So its like   - - - - - - . Inside NgFor i have 18 elements. So it will be like 3 rows and 6 columns.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, You have 1 `td` for each `tr` (row), so buttons are displayed vertically. What you have to do is decide on the number of rows and columns you want to have.

In your case you should divide array returned from `this.getKeyValues(this.navbarService.countriesOzetInfo[0].properties)` to `array` of `array`, i.e. `[[property1 to property6],[property7 to property12],[property13 to property18]]`

So, you can use array of array to repeat rows and columns using `*ngFor`, on both `tr` and `td`.

Divide the array into `rows` and `columns` in `component`. i.e.

```
getRows() {
    let rows= [];;
    let tempArray=
    this.getKeyValues(this.navbarService.countriesOzetInfo[0].properties;
    let i,j,chunk = 6;
    for (i=0,j=tempArray.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
        rows[i]= array.slice(i,i+chunk);
    }
    return rows;  
}
```

Approach 1: using one `array` variable that determines the columns and then use `*ngFor`

```
   <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
          <table class="table">
            <tr *ngFor="let row of rows"> <!-- rows is newly created array of array-->
                <td *ngFor="let column of  row "> <!-- row array that has details about columns-->
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
                    <br/>Apps</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**All the best**

Comment: Hey thanks. The first approach is not working. The second approach gives me 18 rows with 6 element in each of it which is not what i want.

Comment: I just want to have them side by side horizontally.

Comment: That means you have 18 items returned from `this.getKeyValues(this.navbarService.countriesOzetInfo[0].properties)` call!   Bye the way, you dont have to use `this.` in the template, unless its an variable pointing to other `object`

Comment: @myadsmail, You need to divide the array into rows and columns. have one more method in `component` which does that.